# Управление плеером в шторке устройства

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! Разрабатываю приложение на андроид. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать управление плеером в шторке устройства. 
Я новичок в этом, так что надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: вы имеете в виду добавить в ваше приложение уведомление с кнопками back - play/pause - next ?

Comment: @СергейГрушин да, именно.

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Начните изучать уведомления, и рано или поздно вы дойдете до обработки нажатия на кнопки в них.

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день! Для построения уведомления используйте NotificationCompat.Builder и метод setStyle. В библиотеке AppCompat v7 доступен стиль с кнопками управления проигрывателем - NotificationCompat.MediaStyle.

У вас должны быть подключены библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
```

Пример кода:

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
     .setContentTitle("Track title")
     .setContentText("Artist - Album")
     .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap))
     .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
         .setMediaSession(mySession))
     .build();
```

Документация:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle.html
Статья с примером использования MediaSession:
https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-android-media-style-notifications-with-media-session-controls/165